# Multiple web apps on a laptop friendly way

Tags: ruby, nginx, ruby-on-rails, passenger

I have a large collection of mini web apps written in Rails and Sinatra which I constantly use. My objective is to host them in a *laptop friendly* way.

Most of deployment articles I have seen are targeted for servers with Unicorn / Puma / Passenger / Thin... process running on the background. Since I was not sure how much of a battery impact could be having so many Ruby based apps running in the background, I survived so far starting each app individually as needed.

How could I deploy all my apps for localhost use only in a energy efficient way? I do not want  multiple ruby proccesses running on the background all the time, or avoiding my laptop going into sleep.

As a note if that matters: Each of my apps run on their own port number and some of them prefix them through nginx.

Comment: Do you need the applications at all times? Have you considered running VirtualBox to virtualize each application? Also, depending on the applications, you could push them to Heroku which means that they would reside online instead of your local machine.

Comment: They should not be up at all times, most of them are used only 3 times a week for a short period. However at least one of them is used daily.  Considering how resource intensive VirtualBox is, it seems to me like something that defeats my objectives: low cpu and no laptop sleep impact. Heroku is not alternative either since many of my apps touch/explore my local filesystem, read logs, trigger local network events... crazy hacks intended to run only on my laptop.

Comment: Have you looked into Parallels Containers? They have a open beta for Windows right now. 

Instead of full KVM virtualization, these are containers (think OpenVZ) but for Windows. There is a common underlying hardware virtualization and the containers run 'semi-full' instances but share resources of the underlying virtualization. This allows a much better bang for the buck than KVM. If your host OS is linux, you should look into OpenVZ. If it is Windows then look into Parallels Containers. This must be installed on a Windows Server OS though.

Answer (score 0):

If all the apps share same ruby version and same gem setup, I'd rather run all the apps one by one independently when it's needed, mayby shielded by pound reverse proxy (for hiding various ports behind various url prefixes).

If you need isolate environments, take a look at docker https://www.docker.io/ which provides lightweight and lightning-fast application containers.